# ApacheCXF Example Error

Tags: java, apache, web-services

I'm trying to run through this ApacheCXF Tutorial that I found at http://kevinboone.net/cxftest.html
using Intellij.

When compiling the code I keep getting.

**Error:**

```
(17, 34) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class TestMeSoapPortImpl
location: class com.cxftest.server.TestmePort_TestMeSoapPort_Server
```

I have no idea why.

```
public class TestmePort_TestMeSoapPort_Server{

protected TestmePort_TestMeSoapPort_Server() throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println("Starting Server");
    Object implementor = new TestMeSoapPortImpl();
    String address = "http://127.0.0.1:9000/cxftest/testme";
    Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception { 
    new TestmePort_TestMeSoapPort_Server();
    System.out.println("Server ready..."); 

    Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000); 
    System.out.println("Server exiting");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

---------- Structure

A. com.cxftext.server

1. cxftest.wsdl
2. CXFTestImpl (Class)
3. CXFTestService (Class)
4. ObjectFactory (Class)
5. package-info.java
6. Server (Class)
7. TestMe (Class)
8. TestmePort (Interface)
9. TestmePort_TestMeSoapPort_Server (Class)
10. TestMeResponse (Class)

{
    Starting Server
Sep 16, 2014 12:42:41 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://kevinboone.net/cxftest}CXFTestService from WSDL: file: com/cxftest/server/cxftest.wsdl
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:152)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240)
    at com.cxftest.server.Server.(Server.java:15)
    at com.cxftest.server.Server.main(Server.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.(WSDLServiceFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:525)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:261)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'file: com/cxftest/server/cxftest.wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  com\cxftest\server\cxftest.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2390)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2422)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:231)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  com\cxftest\server\cxftest.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
    ... 24 more

Process finished with exit code 1

}
My goal is to perform all tasks in Intellij and become familiar with ApacheCXF using the wsdl2java tool.

Thank you

Comment: Did you import `TestMeSoapPortImpl`?

Comment: Yes. Please see below structure.

Comment: I was able to get a little further. I created TestMeSoapPortImpl class and it compiled. See Error when creating service. Pasted in above text